# Building a quiz - it works but only on the first question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the process of building a quiz sort of game using JQuery. My game works how I wish it to currently, but only for the first question.

```js
var progress = 0;
var score = 0;

var running = true;

var questions = [
  {question: 'Which character is played by Robert Downey Junior?', answers: ['Thor', 'Iron Man', 'Captain America', 'Star Lord'], correct: 'Iron Man'},
  {question: 'What colour is the star on Captain Americas shield?', answers: ['Red', 'Silver/Grey', 'Blue', 'Yellow/Gold'], correct: 'Silver/Grey'}
];

var $quiz = $('.quiz');
var $question = $('#quiz-question');
var $answers = $('#answers');
var $next = $('#next');
var $results = $('#results');

var showQuestion = q => {
  if (progress < questions.length) {
    $question.html(q.question);
    $answers.html(' ');
    q.answers.forEach(function(ans) {
      $answers.append("<div class='answer'>" + ans + "</div>");
    })
  } else {
    $results.html("<h2>Your Results:</h2><p>You scored " + score + "/" + questions.length + "</p>");
    $quiz.hide();
    $results.show();
  }
};

showQuestion(questions[progress]);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $next.hide();
  $results.hide();

  $('.answer').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).html() === questions[progress].correct && running) {
      progress++;
      running = false;
      score++;
      $(this).css('color', 'green');
      $(this).css('border', '3px solid green');
      $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
      $next.show();
    } else if ($(this).html() !== questions[progress] && running) {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
      $(this).css('border', '3px solid red');
      $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
      progress++;
      running = false;
      $next.show();
    }
  })

  $next.on('click', function() {
    running = true;
    showQuestion(questions[progress]);
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #c7ecee;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

main {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

main .quiz {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

main .quiz #quiz-question {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #4d4d4d;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main .quiz #answers {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
}

main .quiz #answers .answer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main .quiz #answers .answer:hover {

}

div#ui {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .75rem;
}

div#ui button {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <main>
    <div class='quiz'>
      <div id='quiz-question'>
      </div>
      <div id='answers'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='results'>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div id='ui'>
    <button id='next'>Next</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, a question and its answers are displayed, when an answer is clicked it stops running the game, so that no other answers can be clicked (or an answer can't be clicked more than once to boost score). When the question is answered, a button appears at the bottom to go to the next question. If there are no more questions, it shows you the results display.

This works exactly how I wish - for one question. When I add any further questions, it displays the question exactly as it should, but the on click effects are no longer applied. I assume this is to do with the elements not existing when the `$(document).ready()` function is called. Could anyone shed any light on how I could solve this problem?

Edited to include code snippet. Uncomment the second quest

Comment: Can you share html code too? Or better make JsFiddle.

Comment: HTML: https://github.com/DannyXCII/mcu-quiz/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Put it into a code snippet (CTRL + M). This will allow you to have a complete working example of your issue embedded in your question.

Comment: I have added the HTML to the original post now... I'm not sure why I received a down vote on this question? It really does put new developers off of asking questions on this website...

Comment: Thanks @Damon, I will see if I can do that now - didn't know about this feature.

Comment: Put all of the relvant code (HTML / JS / CSS) into the snippet. You should be able to click "Run" and encounter your problem.

Comment: No prob! you will get help quicker that way :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 37, change:

```
$('.answer').on('click', function(){
```

to

```
 $('body').on('click', '.answer', function(){
```

The thing is, when you write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $next.hide();
    $results.hide();

    $('.answer').on('click', function(){
```

You target all elements (at current moment) that have the class `.answer`. Since this is only the first question (in the beginning) it won't work at the questions after the first one.

If you instead write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $next.hide();
    $results.hide();

    $('body').on('click', '.answer', function(){
```

You tell jQuery to add the `click`-event to any current and new elements that will be added with the class `.answer` (within the `body`-element). It better to keep this specific, for example with an id for the quiz.

Se the whole example:

```js
var progress = 0;
var score = 0;

var running = true;

var questions = [
  {question: 'Which character is played by Robert Downey Junior?', answers: ['Thor', 'Iron Man', 'Captain America', 'Star Lord'], correct: 'Iron Man'},
  {question: 'What colour is the star on Captain Americas shield?', answers: ['Red', 'Silver/Grey', 'Blue', 'Yellow/Gold'], correct: 'Silver/Grey'}
];

var $quiz = $('.quiz');
var $question = $('#quiz-question');
var $answers = $('#answers');
var $next = $('#next');
var $results = $('#results');

var showQuestion = q => {
  if (progress < questions.length) {
    $question.html(q.question);
    $answers.html(' ');
    q.answers.forEach(function(ans) {
      $answers.append("<div class='answer'>" + ans + "</div>");
    })
  } else {
    $results.html("<h2>Your Results:</h2><p>You scored " + score + "/" + questions.length + "</p>");
    $quiz.hide();
    $results.show();
  }
};

showQuestion(questions[progress]);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $next.hide();
  $results.hide();

  $('body').on('click', '.answer', function(){
    if($(this).html() === questions[progress].correct && running) {
      progress++;
      running = false;
      score++;
      $(this).css('color', 'green');
      $(this).css('border', '3px solid green');
      $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
      $next.show();
    } else if ($(this).html() !== questions[progress] && running) {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
      $(this).css('border', '3px solid red');
      $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
      progress++;
      running = false;
      $next.show();
    }
  })

  $next.on('click', function() {
    running = true;
    showQuestion(questions[progress]);
  })
})
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class='quiz'>
      <div id='quiz-question'>
      </div>
      <div id='answers'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='results'>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div id='ui'>
    <button id='next'>Next</button>
  </div>

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' integrity='sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
  <script src='includes/js/main.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This did the trick, thank you very much! I will now go and read up on this method of targeting, I was unaware about the extra parameters of the ```.on()``` method. Edit: & you just explained it, thanks thanks thanks!!

Comment: Great! If you're happy with my answer, please accept it as correct - thanks! =)

Comment: @D.Winning - Not 100% sure, but in the beginning it was kind of lacking a good description of the problem (lack of complete code, not very well formated code, etc.). The better information, the better chance of a good answer :)

Comment: @D.Winning people on this site are eager to mash "downvote". Your original question was poorly formatted (relative to the expectations of this site) and did not contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would hope that now that you've improved the formatting, those people will re-consider their downvotes or at least explain them in the comments.

Comment: @D.Winning also don't get discouraged by it - there's always going to be unhelpful observers, there was nothing glaringly wrong with your original post. In general, you want to try and keep your question as concise as possible, do a bit of research to see if it has been asked before, include an MCVE as linked above, and don't ask people to do all the work for you. If you do those things, there is no reason for downvotes.

Comment: Thanks both, you've both been really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal edit to get your code working:

```js
var progress = 0;
var score = 0;

var running = true;

var questions = [
  {question: 'Which character is played by Robert Downey Junior?', answers: ['Thor', 'Iron Man', 'Captain America', 'Star Lord'], correct: 'Iron Man'},
  {question: 'What colour is the star on Captain Americas shield?', answers: ['Red', 'Silver/Grey', 'Blue', 'Yellow/Gold'], correct: 'Silver/Grey'}
];

var $quiz = $('.quiz');
var $question = $('#quiz-question');
var $answers = $('#answers');
var $next = $('#next');
var $results = $('#results');

var showQuestion = q => {
  if (progress < questions.length) {
    $question.html(q.question);
    $answers.html(' ');
    q.answers.forEach(function(ans) {
      $answers.append("<div class='answer'>" + ans + "</div>");
    })

    $('.answer').on('click', function(){
      if($(this).html() === questions[progress].correct && running) {
        progress++;
        running = false;
        score++;
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
        $(this).css('border', '3px solid green');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $next.show();
      } else if ($(this).html() !== questions[progress] && running) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        $(this).css('border', '3px solid red');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        progress++;
        running = false;
        $next.show();
      }
    })
  } else {
    $results.html("<h2>Your Results:</h2><p>You scored " + score + "/" + questions.length + "</p>");
    $quiz.hide();
    $results.show();
  }
};

showQuestion(questions[progress]);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $next.hide();
  $results.hide();

  $next.on('click', function() {
    running = true;
    showQuestion(questions[progress]);
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #c7ecee;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

main {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

main .quiz {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

main .quiz #quiz-question {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #4d4d4d;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main .quiz #answers {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
}

main .quiz #answers .answer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main .quiz #answers .answer:hover {

}

div#ui {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .75rem;
}

div#ui button {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class='quiz'>
      <div id='quiz-question'>
      </div>
      <div id='answers'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='results'>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div id='ui'>
    <button id='next'>Next</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, you were attaching an event listener to `.answer` elements once, then replacing those elements, which means when a user clicks the new ones, nothing happens. Here, we add the listeners every time a question is created.

Keep in mind, there are ways you can refactor this code. I would look into event delegation if you want to avoid creating listeners for every `.answer` element.